# Why can't I assign a property to an object using bracket notation + a variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm very new to Vuex, and trying to assign a value to a Vuex state, (`state.map.status.isReady` for this one).

However, I want to make my code reusable, so I created a function `changeMapStatus(state, key, value)` in order to achieve that.

This function modifies the property `state.map.status.key` to `value` it received.

However, when I call the mutation with `this.$store.commit('changeMapStatus', 'isReady', true)` from a component file, it simply removes the `state.map.status.isReady` and that property becomes `undefined`.

On the another hand, if I change the function to

```
changeMapStatus(state, value) {
  state.map.status.isReady = value;
}
```

it somehow works.

Can you help me which point I get it wrong?

Thanks so much!

---

**store.js** (Vuex)

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    map: {
      status: {
        isReady: false,
      },
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    changeMapStatus(state, key, value) {
      state.map.status[key] = value;
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: did you find my answer useful?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, I do. However, I still can't get my head around why that happened.

Comment: it simply that function accepts two parameters so to deal with that you should pass a second parameter as an object wrapping all what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `Vuex` [official docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#commit-with-payload), mutation takes 2 parameters state and payload. You can use the spread operator to get values from the payload.

```
changeMapStatus(state, {key, value}) {
  state.map.status[key] = value;
}

this.$store.commit('changeMapStatus', {key: 'isReady', value: true})
```

Or else you can use it like this

```
changeMapStatus(state, payload) {
  state.map.status = {
      ...state.map.status,
      ...payload,
  }
}

this.$store.commit('changeMapStatus', { isReady: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an object as parameter that contains `key` and `value` as follows :

```
changeMapStatus(state, myObj) {
  state.map.status[myObj.key] = myObj.value;
}
```

and call it like:

```
this.$store.commit('changeMapStatus', {key:'isReady', value:true})
```